# Injected Application and Play.current in Play! Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an `Actor` with injected `Application` and in it's `preStart` method

```
override def preStart = {
    println(application)
    println(Play.current)
  }
```

The actor is created using `bindActor` from `AkkaGuiceSupport` so it's using `asEagerSingleton`

When I start the app the result is that `application` is defined while printing `Play.current` throws exception.

```
play.api.DefaultApplication@59b04da4
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - There is no started application
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
```

Is the `Play.current` some different application than the injected one?

Comment: If you already have an application instance, why do you need `Play.current`?

Comment: I used to have only `Play.current`. I made some changes and it stopped working. It seems that I'll have to inject application everywhere I'm using `Play.current`. I'm just curious why it's not started when injected application is started.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell where you might be going wrong without more context, but if you look at how `Play.current` is implemented... it leads to the need for a call to: `Play.start(application)`

following the chain:

- https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Play.scala#L90
- https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Play.scala#L70
- https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Play.scala#L104

that last line above is the only place where an application gets set such that `Play.current` will reach it, so if you're getting that exception then your application has not been started in the way that play expects.

if i had to guess, i'd say that your actor is getting initialized somewhere before `Play.start` gets called.

Comment: So it looks like application is created and injected and then `Play.start` is called. Not very intuitive. In one case there's an application in the other there's not.